# How to make python tkinter save new data to the CSV file already loaded in the application

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, canvas

This code will not create new data and save it to the Python file. Also if it it not too hard, can you please make it look better and easier to read? The Canvas is also really big even though I have it as x=0 and y=0

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk, messagebox, simpledialog
from customtkinter import *
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image

class RoadSafetyApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Initialization of the main window
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Road Safety App")
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.master.configure(bg="lightgray")
        self.data = []
        self.current_page = 0
        self.rows_per_page = 30

        # Canvas for the Treeview
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # Frame for the Treeview
        self.tree_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.tree_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # Treeview widget for displaying data
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tree_frame)
        self.tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        # Horizontal scrollbar for the Treeview
        self.scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tree_frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        self.scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_x.set)

        # Vertical scrollbar for the Treeview
        self.scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tree_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_y.set)

        # Buttons and entry widgets for user interaction
        self.edit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.master, text="Admin", command=self.admin_edit)
        self.edit_button.pack(side="left")

        self.load_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.master, text="Load CSV", command=self.load_data)
        self.load_button.pack(side="left")

        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(self.master, bg='white', fg="black", relief='groove', width=20)
        self.search_entry.pack(side="left", pady='10', padx='10')

        self.column_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(self.master, values=[], state="readonly", width=15)
        self.column_dropdown.pack(side="left", pady='10', padx='10')

        self.search_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.master, text="Search", command=self.search_data)
        self.search_button.pack(side="left")

        self.next_page_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.master, text="Scroll Down", command=self.next_page)
        self.next_page_button.pack(side="right")

        self.help_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.master, text="Help", command=self.show_help)
        self.help_button.pack(side="right")

        # Frame for displaying row data
        self.row_data_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="lightgray", pady='10')
        self.row_data_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        # Binding event to the Treeview
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.show_row_data)
    def load_csv(self, file_path):
        """
        Load data from a CSV file and return a list of dictionaries.
        Each dictionary represents a row with column names as keys.
        """
        try:
            with open(file_path, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
                csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                data = list(csvreader)
                return data
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Error loading CSV file: {e}")
            return []

    # Method for displaying help information
    def show_help(self):
        help_text = """
        Welcome to Queensland Crashes!
        Instructions:
        1. Load the car crash CSV that you want to read about
        2. Use the search button to find specific data
        3. Use the scroll down button to scroll down if more rows are available

        FOR ADMIN -
        1. Press on Admin
        2. Input password - (Password1)
        3. Edit Data
        """
        messagebox.showinfo("Help", help_text)

    # Method for initiating admin edit
    def admin_edit(self):
        password = simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter the password:", show='*')
        if password == "Password1":
            self.edit_data_window()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Authentication Error", "Invalid password!")


    # Method for creating the edit data window
    def edit_data_window(self):
        if not self.data:
            messagebox.showwarning("No Data", "Load a CSV file first.")
            return

        edit_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        edit_window.title("Edit Data")

        scrollbar_y_edit = tk.Scrollbar(edit_window, orient="vertical")
        scrollbar_y_edit.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        scrollbar_x_edit = tk.Scrollbar(edit_window, orient="horizontal")
        scrollbar_x_edit.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        edit_canvas = tk.Canvas(edit_window, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y_edit.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x_edit.set)
        edit_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        edit_frame = tk.Frame(edit_canvas, bg="lightgray")
        edit_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=edit_frame, anchor="nw")

        scrollbar_y_edit.config(command=edit_canvas.yview)
        scrollbar_x_edit.config(command=edit_canvas.xview)

        columns = list(self.data[0].keys())

        entry_labels = []
        entry_values = []

        # Creating entry widgets for each column
        for i, col in enumerate(columns):
            tk.Label(edit_frame, text=f"{col}:", bg="lightgray").grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
            entry = tk.Entry(edit_frame, bg='white', fg="black", relief='groove', width=20)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
            entry_labels.append(col)
            entry_values.append(entry)

        # Button for saving edited data
        save_button = tk.Button(edit_frame, text="Save Data", command=lambda: self.save_edited_data(entry_labels, entry_values, edit_window), bg='black', fg="white", relief='groove', pady='10', padx='10')
        save_button.grid(row=len(columns), column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        # Configuring scroll region for canvas
        edit_frame.update_idletasks()
        edit_canvas.config(scrollregion=edit_canvas.bbox("all"))
        edit_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: edit_canvas.configure(scrollregion=edit_canvas.bbox("all")))

    # Method for saving edited data
    def save_edited_data(self, entry_labels, entry_values, edit_window):
        print("Saving edited data...")  # Add this line for debugging

        edited_row = {}
        for label, entry in zip(entry_labels, entry_values):
            edited_row[label] = entry.get()

        print("Edited row:", edited_row)  # Add this line for debugging

        # Find the selected row in the original data
        selected_item = self.tree.selection()
        if selected_item:
            # Extracting row index from the row ID
            row_id = selected_item[0]
            row_index = int(row_id.split('C')[1]) - 1
            print("Editing row ID:", row_index)  # Add this line for debugging
            self.data[row_index] = edited_row

            # Save the updated data to the CSV file
            file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".csv", filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])
            if file_path:
                with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=list(self.data[0].keys()))
                    csvwriter.writeheader()
                    csvwriter.writerows(self.data)

                messagebox.showinfo("Save", "Data saved successfully!")
                edit_window.destroy()
        else:
            print("No row selected for editing!")  # Add this line for debugging

    # Method for loading data from CSV
    def load_data(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])
        if file_path:
            self.data = self.load_csv(file_path)
            if self.data:
                self.display_data()

    # Method for displaying data in the Treeview
    def display_data(self):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        self.tree.configure(show="headings")
        if not self.data:
            print("No data to display")
            return

        columns = list(self.data[0].keys())
        self.tree["columns"] = columns

        for col in columns:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor='center')
            self.tree.column(col, width=150, anchor='w')

        self.column_dropdown["values"] = columns
        self.column_dropdown.set(columns[0])

        start_idx = self.current_page * self.rows_per_page
        end_idx = start_idx + self.rows_per_page
        current_page_data = self.data[start_idx:end_idx]

        for i, row in enumerate(current_page_data):
            values = [row.get(col, "") for col in columns]
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=values)

        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    # Method for navigating to the next page
    def next_page(self):
        total_pages = len(self.data) // self.rows_per_page + 1
        if self.current_page < total_pages - 1:
            self.current_page += 1
            self.display_data()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Page Errors", "There is nothing else to scroll down to!")

    # Method for searching data
    def search_data(self):
        query = self.search_entry.get().lower()
        selected_column = self.column_dropdown.get()
        result_rows = [row for row in self.data if query in str(row.get(selected_column, "")).lower()]
        self.display_search_results(result_rows)

    # Method for displaying search results in the Treeview
    def display_search_results(self, result_rows):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        columns = list(self.data[0].keys())
        self.tree["columns"] = columns

        for col in columns:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor='center')
            self.tree.column(col, width=150, anchor='center')

        for i, row in enumerate(result_rows):
            values = [row.get(col, "") for col in columns]
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=values)

        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    # Method for displaying detailed row data in a separate window
    def show_row_data(self, event):
        selected_item = self.tree.selection()
        if selected_item:
            row_id = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
            if row_id:
                index_start = next((i for i, char in enumerate(row_id) if char.isdigit()), None)
            if index_start is not None:
                row_index = int(row_id[index_start:])-1
                row_data = (self.data[row_index])
                print(row_data)
                self.display_row_data(row_data)

    # Method for displaying detailed row data in a separate window
    def display_row_data(self, row_data):
        row_data_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        row_data_window.title("Row Data")
        row_data_window.configure(bg="white")

        row_count = 0
        for key, value in row_data.items():
            label = tk.Label(row_data_window, text=f"{key}: {value}", bg="black", fg="white", padx=10, pady=5)
            label.grid(row=row_count // 4, column=row_count % 4, sticky="w")
            row_count += 1

# Main execution
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = customtkinter.CTk()
    bg=PhotoImage(file = "qldgov.png")
    canvas1 = Canvas(root, width = -100, height = -100)
    canvas1.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    canvas1.create_image(0,0, image=bg, anchor = "nw")
    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel
    root.iconbitmap("QLD Icon.ico")
    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
    root.configure(bg="lightgray")
    app = RoadSafetyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried to make it save but all the code wants to do is edit the data and not create new data.

Comment: Your code will raise exception on the line `row_index = int(row_id.split('C')[1]) - 1` inside `save_edited_data()` because *row ID* of a treeview is something like `I001` by default, not `C001`.